# send mail in new Thread in mvc taking time on hosting

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I try to send mail and i don't want to wait for the result , i create new thread and send the mail its working on my pc but when i build the application and upload it to shared hosting its taking to match time like no new thread created and mail send successfully .

```
 Thread sendMailThread = new Thread(() =>
            sendMail(to, body, subject));
            sendMailThread.Start();


        public bool sendMail(string to, string body,string subject)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
            //If you need to authenticate

            client.Port = smtpPort;
            client.EnableSsl = enableSsl;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUser, smtpPass);

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(defaultSender);
            mailMessage.To.Add(to);
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.Body = body;

            client.Send(mailMessage);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**update controller action**

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public void changePassword(string userId, string newPassword)
    {
        var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        ApplicationUser cUser = userManager.FindById(userId);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newPassword)) newPassword = "123456";

        String hashedNewPassword = userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(newPassword);

        UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>();
        store.SetPasswordHashAsync(cUser, hashedNewPassword);
        store.UpdateAsync(cUser);
        context.SaveChanges();

        string mailBody = "Your password has been changed with user name : " + cUser.UserName + " and password: " + newPassword;
    //send mail
        mailService.sendMailThread(cUser.Email, mailBody, "Your password has been changed");
    }
```

**update** why i need to send mail in new thread  ?
i wan't want response wait until mail send , as it take some time .

**update**
this code is working perfect on my local machine with the same SMTP server , but when i upload the site to shared hosting the request taking match time until its returned to browser , and i think send mail blocking my main request thread .

Comment: how do you notice that it takes too much time?
is your main thread blocking or does it just take too long to receive the mail respectively send it (`client.Send`)?

Comment: Where is the code that actually executes the method? Where is the controller action?

Comment: @Arikael its taking much time until i receive the response so i think its blocking the main thread.

Comment: @fligant why do you assume that? The remote server won't work any faster if you send the mail from Thread2 instead of Thread1. Post your code. *How* do you create that thread? Where? Do you actually block waiting for it to complete? Why create a thread at all?

Comment: @fligant is the SMTP server local or remote? With a remote server you can't do anything, except perhasp use a singleton smtpclient to handle all emails. Typically, web applications use a *local* smtp server, or even the IIS SMTP service to send emails immediatelly and have the service forward them to their destination

Comment: this code is working perfect on my local machine with the same SMTP server , but when i upload the site to shared hosting the request taking match time until its returned to browser , and i think send mail blocking my main request thread .

Comment: Where is the main request handling code? Using a separate thread won't block your controller action. Waiting for that thread to complete though, *will* block it. The same with SendMailAsync, although it won't waste a thread doing nothing while waiting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i updated my question controller action added , 
Using a separate thread won't block your controller action yes that's what i want and its working right on my development pc , but on shared hosting request taking match time and i think send mail thread blocking the main request thread .

Comment: First, your action calls `sendMailInThread` yet the method you posted doesn't use a thrad. Second, you don't need to manually create a thread, you can use `Task.Run`. You don't need that either if your method uses `SendMailAsync`, just don't await for the result. The *real* problem in all this though, is that ASP.NET can terminate your thread/task for any number of reasons once a request is complete. With a thread, ASP.NET won't know that there is work left to do. At the very least you need to use [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636892(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @fligant added code that doesn't await and prevents IIS from prematurely terminating the background task.

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need a separate thread to send an email asynchronously. You can use [SenMailAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendmailasync?view=netframework-4.7), eg:

```
public async Task<bool> sendMailAsync(string to, string body,string subject)
{
    ...
    await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
    ...
}

public async Task MyAction(...)
{
    ...
    var success=await sendMailAsync(to,body,subject);
    if(!success)
    {
        Log.Error("Sending failed but I don't know why because I discarded the exception");
    }
    ...
}
```

That won't make *sending* faster though, it means that you don't have to block the request thread while waiting for sending to complete. Using a separate thread won't complete faster either. After all, the remote server won't work faster if you use the request thread or another thread.

In fact, if you use a background thread and wait for it to complete, you harm performance. The request thread will be blocked waiting for another thread to do what the request thread could do as easily. With `await` the request thread is released and execution resumes after `await`.

Web sites and applications typically use a *local* smtp server or even IIS's SMTP service to send emails immediatelly and avoid waiting for responses from remote servers. You could build a queue to send emails asynchronously, but that's exactly what the SMTP service does in the first place.

**UPDATE**

If you can't use an SMTP Service and don't won't to wait for the send operation, you'll have to create a fire-and-forget action in a safe way. Simply using a Thread, or removing `await` isn't enough. ASP.NET can recycle an AppDomain for any number of reasons, terminating your thread/task with it. [Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) explains the various techniquest used to run a background task safely. One of them is to *tell* ASP.NET that you have a background task, with [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636892(v=vs.110).aspx). IIS will wait up to 90 seconds for a background task to terminate before recycling.

To register a background email task :

```
public async Task MyAction(...)
{
    ...
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>sendMailAsync(to,body,subject));
    ...
}
```

Comment: var success=await sendMailAsync(to,body,subject);
is't await will prevent request return until the mail complete ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SendAsyncMail()
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress("Enter from mail address");
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("Enter to address #1"));
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("Enter to address #2"));
    mail.Subject = "Enter mail subject";
    mail.Body = "Enter mail body";

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    Object state = mail;

    //event handler for asynchronous call
    smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(smtpClient_SendCompleted);
    try
    {
        smtpClient.SendAsync(mail, state);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { /* exception handling code here */ }
}

void smtpClient_SendCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mail = e.UserState as MailMessage;

    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error!=null)
    {
        message.Text = "Mail sent successfully";
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't run any faster than a blocking send inside a separate thread. In any case, code-only answers are *not* good answers. At the very least explain why this would solve the problem and what it does

Comment: BTW, SmtpClient is obsolete and Microsoft's own [documentation for the class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7) advises to avoid it in favor of MailKit

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problems. They were usually caused by one of the following reasons

- email server is slow
- network issues
- relaying issues (your local connection probably accesses your SMTP Server differently than via your hosting)
- using the wrong port (we had the problem that multiple ports were possible, but some, probably deprecated ones, were significantly slower
- using unsecure connection where a SSL Connection was expected (again, it worked but much slower)

that means usually the client code itself wasn't really the problem.

You could check the port on which you connect to your SMTP Server and try sending it with and without an SSL connection.

Or you can, as mentioned by others, send your mails asynchronously. Either use some `BackgroundWorker`, `Task`, just fire and forget (probably not an ideal solution) or by using a fullfledged framework like [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

I think the error/problem is not in your code but somewhere in the communication between shared hosting and your SMTP Server.

Comment: I think the error/problem is not in your code but somewhere in the communication between shared hosting and your SMTP Server.
the mail sent success , but if mail sending from other thread and there is problem why the request thread waiting the other thread .

Comment: see @Panagiotis Kanavos [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040114/send-mail-in-new-thread-in-mvc-taking-time-on-hosting/44042136?noredirect=1#comment75110233_44040114)

As mentioned if you don't reuse your second Thread's result nothing should block. You can test it by logging for example.

And I assume that by "response" you mean the response from `client.Send`?

Receiving a slow response from `client.Send` has nothing to do with Threading but with the SMTP Server responding slow.